# Escape password when using DirectorySearcher?

Tags: security, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to figure out if we need to escape password (we do escape username) if you are using the `DirectorySearcher` and passing it a `DirectoryEntry` with the username and password set.

Here's the code shorthand:

```
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(domain);
directoryEntry.Username = escaped(username);
directoryEntry.Password = password;

new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry)
{
SearchScope = searchScope,
Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)" + escaped(filter) + ")"
};
```

Would not escaping the password make the code vulnerable to injection? Would escaping the password cause the validation of the `DirectoryEntry` to fail?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to escape the username or password passed in for binding.

Comment: Thanks. I sort of figured that but better safe than sorry.